# Exponential Levy process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

We assume that the stochastic process L is a Levy process with the predictable characteristics triplet $(b,c,\nu)$. Which integrability conditions we should assume for the new stochastic process 
 $$S=e^L$$ to be a semimartingale??

Comment: Is that $L$ is a semimartingale?
If yes, then $S$ is also because $x\rightarrow e^x$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since every Lévy process $(L_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is a semimartingale, you can take Itô's formula (see e.g. Protter Chpt. II) with the function $x\mapsto \text{e}^x$ (as @bmo said) to conclude that the stochastic process
$$
(\text{e}^{L_t})_{t\ge 0} 
$$
is a semimartingale and no further moment assumptions on the Lévy process are necessary!